# Can't open DPM 2012 Console

Tags: scdpm

I've got a DPM 2012 SP1 installation running on Server 2012 with a locally installed SQL Server 2008 R2 10.50.4000.0. DPM was an upgrade from DPM 2012 RTM, via an intermediary upgrade to DPM 2012 CU3, but since the upgrade I can't open the console. I get this message:
"Unable to connect to DPMNAME.domain.tld (ID: 948)
Verify that the DPM service is running on this computer"

There is a "more information" link (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee958049.aspx), which as usual goes to a Microsoft "page cannot be found" URL :)

I've researched this issue quite a bit and I've followed the Microsoft page http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934577.aspx which asks you to make sure that these services are running:

- DPM (MSDPM)
- DPM Access Manager Service (DPMAMService)
- DPM Writer (DpmWriter)
- DPMLA (DPM Library Agent)
- DPMRA (DPM Replication Agent)

I can't get the service DPMRA to start though:

`"Error 1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"`

If I look in the system event there is a 7009 event saying
`"A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the DPMRA service to connect."` but that is inaccurate - the error happens instantly and certainly not after 30 seconds.

Other event errors:
Event 7023:

```
“The DPM service terminated with the following error: 
    %%4294967295”
```

Also Event 10010:

`“The server {27F60283-447F-4D5F-AA84-F45D09BD06EF} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.”`

In Application there is a 3750 event but it doesn’t have all the information

`“The description for Event ID 3750 from source MSDPM cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.”`

It does have this text which indicates that the CU3 update didn’t complete properly though I don’t remember seeing any errors after install:

```
“Version 4.0.1908.0 of the DPM database, and version 4.1.3313.0 of the DPM application are not compatible.”
```

Any ideas about what I should try to resolve this?

Thanks